# Changing default repository location of Play Framework 2.2.x?

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

I use Play **2.2.0**.

I have set maven repository location to `F:\repository` but I have no idea how to change the default repository location of play that's under `\play-2.2.0\repository`. It's very annoying that I have two repositories in my computer.

I tried to find some information about configuring `\framework\sbt\sbt.boot.properties` and `\framework\sbt\sbt.boot.properties` but still no joy.

How can I have a single repository for Maven and Play Framework?